# How to convert data from .gitignore into list of regexp-es in Perl

Tags: git, perl, gitignore

Here is my problem. I have some project in git with `.gitignore` file. I want to do some work in Perl script with the files that are not listed in `.gitignore` (actually I want to test all the files that are commited with the module [Test::Whitespaces](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aWhitespaces)).

What is the easiest way to parse `.gitignore` in Perl and to convert in to the list of regexpes so I can use that list and to pass it to `ignore` section of [Test::Whitespaces](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aWhitespaces)?

Comment: Why not user `git ls-files` to get a list of all the tracked files and pass that in via the `files` parameter?

Comment: Yes, thank you @jszakmeister. This is one more possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `glob` which can use directly the expressions from .gitignore, and then just subtract the resulting files from the list of all files in a directory?

Comment: Yep, that is a solution. Thank you for the great idea. =) But I'm still interested in finding other ways to solve this problems, maybe there is simplier solution.